How to set laravel reveb system when I host my file?
I set Laravel Reverb on my Laravel 11 proejct. WHen i Ran it loccally its smoothly working. but when I host it then here show me some error . in console. and its not working. Agaain when npm run build it show me another error
here is my problem
pace.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8080/app/re7tqf2g1upi4tlpmoqo?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed: 

npm run buld problem
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5773
return await WebAssembly.instantiate(mod, {
^
RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance
at lazyllhttp (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5773:32)
Node.js v23.1.0
how can I solve this problem
